# product_count dont work when calling product to frontpage

Tags: product, cms, cms-block

Im trying to call 3 products from each category on my frontpage.

im using this code to call one category

> {{block type="catalog/product_list" product_count="3" category_id="3"
>   template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

but it takes alle products from the category. 
Why is the product_count dont work?

UPDATE:
After i tried a new magento installment, it worked for a while, but now it dosen't again. Can someone please tell me why? its a pretty annoing thing :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 {{block type="catalog/product_list" limit="3" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: I've change the category_id to be the right on. but still no luck :(

Comment: use `limit` instead of `product_count`

Comment: yeah thats what i've tried, no luck